# Align everything to centre

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

i'm not a web designer but i making a website and i have run into something which may be very easy. how would i align everything to centre no matter what the screen size is. In this case in the Scroll component i'm returning a Post component which return a react-bootstrap Thumbnails which i want to align centre in the Scroll component(imagine aligning bootstrap cards to centre). Any help would be really appreciated thanks.

//post component

```
<Thumbnail className = "post">
<img src="https://robohash.org/abc"></img>
<h3>facemash user</h3>
<div>
    <ButtonGroup>
        <Button bsStyle = 'success' bsSize="small">
            <Glyphicon glyph="thumbs-up" /> Clap
        </Button>
        <Button bsStyle = 'info' bsSize="small">
            <Glyphicon glyph="edit" /> Comment
        </Button>
        <Button bsStyle = 'danger' bsSize="small">
            <Glyphicon glyph="share" /> Share
        </Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
</div>
</Thumbnail>
```

//Scroll component

```
<div className = "scroll">
    {props.children}
</div>
```

//Main component

```
    <Scroll> 
        <Post/> // these should centre align
        <Post/>
        <Post/>
    </Scroll>
```

// all CSS styles

```
/*Main*/

.Main{
    min-height: 98%;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Scroll Component*/

.scroll{
    /*background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, lime);*/
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    text-align: center;
    border:4px solid  pink;
}

/*Post*/

.post{
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Code Ninja,
Have you tried the following for what you want to center? margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use flex-box you should be set up parrent container some styling to align children center:

```
.scroll{
 /*background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, lime);*/
 min-height: 100%;
 font-size: 24px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 text-align: center;
 border:4px solid  pink;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you saved me. Working just fine.

Comment: @Code Ninja Your Welcome.)